# RSA Public Key Exponents of 16 bytes

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I am writing a software that is using a public key that has 16 bytes in the Exponents

I have the following code

```
string longKey = @"-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGWAoGBAMqfGO9sPz+kxaRh/qVKsZQGul7NdG1gonSS3KPXTjtcHTFfexA4MkGA
mwKeu9XeTRFgMMxX99WmyaFvNzuxSlCFI/foCkx0TZCFZjpKFHLXryxWrkG1Bl9+
+gKTvTJ4rWk1RvnxYhm3n/Rxo2NoJM/822Oo7YBZ5rmk8NuJU4HLAhAYcJLaZFTO
sYU+aRX4RmoF
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----";

using (var reader = new StringReader(longKey))
{
    var pem = new PemReader(reader);
    var o = (RsaKeyParameters)pem.ReadObject();
    using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        var parameters = new RSAParameters
        {
            Modulus = o.Modulus.ToByteArray(),
            Exponent = o.Exponent.ToByteArray()
        };
        rsa.ImportParameters(parameters);

    //other code is here that uses the rsa

    }
}
```

The key is used with certain barcodes and was provided to me, but is also available online on different other sites

The problem I am facing is `ImportParameters` is giving an exception that only says 'Bad Data' after research I found that RSACryptoServiceProvider only use 4 bytes in the Exponents but this public key have 16 bytes in the exponents. If I make Exponent to a static byte array 1,0,1 then `ImportParameters` works but obviously the rest of my code fails

Is there another way I can use this key, like C++ or can this be done in C#. I am not an expert in RSA Encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on .NET 4.6 or higher, you can use `RSACng` as a drop-in replacement for `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

It has a bit of an unfortunate support matrix:

- 4.6: RSACng works great, pretty much so long as you only use it in your own code.
- 4.6.1: Some, but not all of the framework libraries understand RSACng objects (RSACryptoServiceProvider was special-cased)
- 4.6.2: Almost all of the framework libraries understand RSACng

RSACng doesn't have a 4-byte restriction on the size of the `Exponent` value.